# JMeter Load Testing Connection Refused

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, load-testing, spring-webclient

I am running a load test on a service that's run on my machine locally to test the Spring WebFlux WebClient. Here is what the setup is like:

```
      /get       /process
JMeter -> Service 1 -> Service 2->| waits for
       <-           <-          <-| 300ms
```

My JMeter script will call the /get endpoint for service 1 which in turn will call the /process call in service 2. Note that Service 1 and Service 2 share the same codebase, but call different endpoints. The process endpoint waits for a specified amount of time (500ms) to simulate some processing, and then return a 200.

Here is the JMeter load I am specifying. It consists about 300 users and gradually ramps up and runs for about 5 minutes.

[image: JMeter Load]

When I run my load test, I am consistently getting the following errors at ~2:00 mark:

Blockquote

> 1693684499199,0,Non-blocking Request,Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException,"Non HTTP response message: Connect to localhost:9090 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect",jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group - 300 Users 1-32,text,false,,2825,0,256,256,http://localhost:9090/get?delay=300&block=false,0,0,0

> 1693684516528,670,Non-blocking Request,Non HTTP response code: java.net.BindException,Non HTTP response message: Address already in use: connect,jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group - 300 Users 1-118,text,false,,2521,0,183,183,http://localhost:9090/get?delay=300&block=false,0,0,670

I have tried to increase the Tomcat max threads and increasing the MaxUserPort in the Windows registry, but none of that has helped. I was wondering if the load that I am specifying is too high for my setup?

Would I be better off running the services and/or JMeter in a separate machine?

Answer (score 0):

1. Increase [ephemeral ports range](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.2.1?topic=listener-windows)
2. Decrease the [maximum time the connection spends in TIME_WAIT state](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.5.x?topic=system-recycling-tcp-connections-microsoft-windows-operating)
3. Increase the [maximum number of network connections if it's below 600](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.5.x?topic=itspmwos-increasing-maximum-number-tcp-connections-microsoft-windows-operating-system)

Also running load generator and the system under test on the same machine is not the best idea

1. because both will be very resource intensive and start struggling for resources, it will be very hard to determine the bottleneck if it's connected with resources usage even if you use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics) so consider at least running JMeter and the system under test on a separate physical machines
2. you cannot rely on the test results you get in the scaled-down environment as they cannot be extrapolated, the stress test should be done in production or production-like environment